# How to make auto refresh total user online?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have used poll to poll the msg from the server but how to enhance it to make the total user online will auto refresh too? Now i need to refresh browser to change the total user online

here is my html

```
<form name ="chatroom">

    <div class="chatroom-upper-info">
        <div class="left-total-user-online" id="left-total-user-online">
            total user online here.....
        </div><div class="load-more-data">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="load" value="Load More Results">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="chatroom-upper-container" id="chatroom-upper-container">
        <div id="inner">
            Loading Message....<img src="../images/loading.gif"/>
        </div>
         <input type="hidden" id="more_message" value="40">
    </div>
    <div class="chatroom-lower-left-container">
        <textarea class="message-setting" id="area-message" placeholder="type text" name= "msg"></textarea>
    </div><div class="chatroom-lower-right-container">
        <button type="button" class="btn sendmessage-btn" onclick= "submitChat()">Send</button>
    </div>  

</form>
```

here is my js

```
function submitChat(){
if(chatroom.msg.value == '' ){
 alert('You didnt input any message');
return;
}

 var msg = chatroom.msg.value;
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
  document.getElementById('inner').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
       }
   }
   xmlhttp.open('GET','chatinsert.php?&msg='+msg, true);
   xmlhttp.send();
   $('.chatroom-upper-container').scrollTop($('.chatroom-upper-container').get(0).scrollHeight);
   }

   $(document).ready(function(e){

  $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
  setInterval(function(){$('#inner').load('chatlogs.php');}, 2000);
  setInterval(function(){$('#left-total-user online').load('user_online.php');}, 2000);

$(".sendmessage-btn").click(function(){
    $("#area-message").val('');     
 });     
});

 (function poll() {
   setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
   url: "http://localhost/pme/main/newchatroom.php", 
   success: function(data) 
   {
        setValue(data.value);
   }, 
   dataType: "json", 
   complete: poll 
   });
}, 
30000
);  
});
```

here is my php for count total user online

```
<?php 

    include '../config.php';

    $sql= mysqli_query($connection,' select * from session');
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($sql)

?>
```

**UPDATE**

this seem work but my page didn't show anything. Any Solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout javascript function and send an ajax request to return the active session count periodically. This will happen in the background and you will not have to reload the page. If you want to reload the page u can do it using setTimeout aswell.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function(){
     location = ''
  },60000)
</script>
```

Comment: setInterval(function(){$('#left-total-user-online').load('user_online.php');}, 2000); I have used this and i seem like work but my page didnt show anything